# Encoding strings to small sizes for QRCode generation

Tags: javascript, algorithm, encoding, qr-code

I'm generating QR codes using strings that could very easily be longer in length then a QRCode could handle. I'm looking for suggestions on algorithms to encode these strings as small as possible, or a proof that the string cannot be shrunk any further.

Since I'm encoding a series of items, I can represent them using ID's and delineate them using pipes as in the following lookup table:

```
    function encodeLookUp(character){
        switch(character){
            case '0': return '0000';
            case '1': return '0001';
            case '2': return '0010';
            case '3': return '0011';
            case '4': return '0100';
            case '5': return '0101';
            case '6': return '0110';
            case '7': return '0111';
            case '8': return '1000';
            case '9': return '1001';
            case '|': return '1010';
            case ':': return '1011';
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Using this table I am already doing a base 16 encoding, therefore each 32 ascii character from the original string becomes half a character in the new string (effectively halving the length).

```
Starting String:  01251548|4654654:4465464 // ID1 | ID2 : ID3   demonstrates both pipes.
Bit String:  000000010010010100010101010010001010010001100101010001100101010010110100010001100101010001100100
Result String:  %H¤eFT´FTd // Half the length of the starting string.
```

Then this new ascii code, is translated according to QRCode specification.

EDIT: The most amount of characters currently encodable: 384

CLARIFICATION: Both ID numberic length, and the quantity of ID's or pipes is variable with a tendancy towards one. I am looking to be able to reduce this algorithm to contain on average the least amount of characters by the time its a 'result string'.

NOTE: The result string is only an ascii represenetaion of the binary string i've encoded with the data to conform with standard QRCode specifications and readers.

Comment: What can your strings contain? You're trying to compress them, so they'd better not be arbitrary, random strings. A related question is, do you need all the information from the string at the decoding end (for example, can you get away with sending a hash)? You'll get more useful answers if you explain the overall pictures.

Comment: I may misunderstand the question... why doesn't a conventional compression algorithm work (gzip, bzip2, huffman-encoding, etc)?

Comment: @Jeremy Powell I am actually using a type of huffman-encode and pruning all the excess nodes (which leaves me with a minimum base 16).

gzip, bzip2 actually create patterned hash tables (or something similar), but over small strings <1kb it will actually make them LONGER. These are only appropriate for large files.

Comment: @Gilles No, as I stated in the question, they represent numeric id's and not something 'arbitrary' although I'm not sure why you would even ask that.. why would anyone be encoding arbitrary strings for any reason anyway..

MY strings contain any one of the 12 characters I indicated in the original post.

Comment: "Since I'm encoding a series of items" do you mean that one QR code needs to contain many items?

Comment: In order to really nail down exactly how small you're strings can be, we need to understand, in some fashion, how *many* items you'll be encoding. When you can say "I have 512 items" then you can be certain that you won't be able to compress your descriptions to smaller than log_2(512) = 9 bits.

Comment: The number of items is dynamic, it changes according to the user so it could be 2 items, or it could be up to 100 items or more.

Each item is represented by a 0-7 character numeric id. I need to encode a string of these dynamically generated id's into a QR code to be decoded on the other side back to their original values.

Comment: @Gregm that's what I was asking before you started bashing my reasoning. By the way, padding IDs (like you did in the first one of your example above) as well as providing a separator defeats the purpose of both systems, increasing the overhead by two.

Comment: @Greg It's going to be a lot easier to figure out an answer if you tell us what the original format of your data is, before any post-processing you're doing, as well as details about what post-processing you're doing.

Comment: @Everyone Sorry if this was not clear. In the second code box where it says: starting string, bit string, result string. _starting_ string, is the original format of my data (go figure), _bit_ string, is after i've encoded using the lookup table supplied. Its deffintion is pretty self explanitory.

Comment: @Greg What you've said seems to indicate that you've already performed huffman encoding - and maybe other things - on the 'starting string', though.

Comment: @Christian Sciberras Sorry christian, I do not mean to 'bash'.

Comment: @Nick Hi Nick, the starting string is simply a list of id's unencoded. Each of those id's represents a row in a database. I've huffman encoded already by removing all other ascii characters except the 12 I need, so at this point making an asymetrical tree would do little to gain anything (if at all..) unless the original string happend to contain only 8 unique characters.. (In this case highly unlickly since I'm dealing with 50+ random 0-9 chars.)

Comment: @Greg Oh, I see - you're referring to the `encodeLookUp` function as huffman encoding. It's actually just a straight transposition, which I suppose you could consider to be a special case of huffman encoding. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a start of an answer to my own question:

If I start with a string of numbers

I can parse that string for patterns and hold those patters in special symbols that are able to take up the other 4 spaces available in my Huffman tree.

EDIT: Example: staring string 12222345, ending string 12x345. Where x is a symbol that means 'repeat the last symbol 3 more times'

Comment: Geez Grey, great job! That's called RLE. [/sarcasm]

Comment: @Greg You're still thinking of numbers as strings of decimal digits. That's only one possible representation, and not a very efficient one for your purposes.

Comment: Well im already encoding the binary as much as possible.. But I can stack other pre-encodings on top to minimize it even more..

Comment: @Greg But you're treating the IDs as sequences of decimal digits, then doing BCD encoding on them. It's more efficient to treat them as integers, and store them in 4, 8, or a variable number of bytes (see my answer). Storing 2^32-1 as a 32 bit integer takes 4 bytes, but storing it in BCD takes 5.

Comment: @Nick Nick, your missing part of the picture here. When I use the look-up table I do _MORE_ then what your suggesting. Not only do I take each didget out of its '8 byte' int, I compress it much more then to 4 bytes, In-fact I compress each number to a half-byte, or only 4 bits. This is what you see in the binary form.

Comment: @Greg You compress each _digit_ to 4 bits. To store the value 2^32-1= 4294967296 you would need 10 * 4 bits = 5 bytes. To store it as a 32-bit integer requires, well, 32 bits = 4 bytes. You still haven't elaborated anywhere on what the constraints on your IDs are - what's their maximum value?

Comment: They have no theoretical maximum value. They are integers, not strings, so 000123 = 123. I see what you mean with store the values as numbers, this could save space for large ids >= 9 didgets . It is highly unlikely that we will have ID's that are >= 9 didgets in length, so using this would actually loose more space then it would gain, as it makes ids like '1' = 2 bits, be 4 bytes.

Comment: @Greg Then a variable-length encoding is your best bet. It still makes more sense than BCD.

Answer (score 0):

Using the function, you're going to loose a lot of space (since 4 bits are way too much storage for 12 combinations).

I'd start by looking at the maximum length possible for your IDs and find a suitable storage block.

If you are storing these items serially in a fixed count (say, 4 ids). You would need id_length*id_count at most, and you won't need to use any separators.

**Edit:** Again according to the number of IDs you want to write and their expected maximum length, there may be different types of encodings to compress it done. RLE (run length encoding) came to my mind.

Comment: Uhm, I hope your confusing bytes with bits, else there is going to be a problem here.

Comment: 4 bits is 2^4 combinations, or 16 combinations. 3 bits would be 8, which is too small.

Comment: @Christian, Are you thinking 3^2 = 9? 2^3 = 2*2*2=8

Comment: @Jeremy - Ah, right, had the earlier one scribbled on my desk for a different purpose (in fact it was about 3 different characters). Don't know how I jumped to that conclusion (my bad).

Comment: This answer was both incorrect and wrong. Incorrect as in 'id_length*id_count at most' is both obvious, and below the complexity of the algorithm I have already presented in the question, and wrong as in you didn't provide any algorithm or solution whatsoever.

Comment: As another answer pertaining to some (irrelevant) point you made: These id blocks are of varying length (to _SAVE_ space).

Comment: Why would I ever want to write their expected maximum length and not their actual maximum length? This seems to be going backwards from my answer. Also, there is no theoretical maximum expected number.

Comment: Greg - I clearly asked whether your ID list is of a varying length or not. The answer to that question clearly changes what the right solution is. Again, this is why I mentioned id_length*id_count, which does help serving a solution if and only if the earlier question was actually answered. There's no such thing as complexity to your algorithm, you are simply converting a set of values using a table. This doesn't compress your data any more than the raw values in the first place (you're still saving the raw values in a serial format, you're simply trying to loose ascii overhead).

Comment: With regards to saving space, that is a very relevant point of mine. This has again got to do with the question I asked (and as of yet unanswered). The reason behind this is simply. If you want to store data of a fixed size, you don't need to care about saving space, except making sure it fits. Let's say you have 4 IDs at most, and each ID can be 65535 in size at most, that means you need an "unsigned short" that is, 8 bytes (16 bits). 4 IDs would at most require 32 bytes.

Comment: Of course there *must* be a theoretical maximum number, otherwise you can't store an ID of a certain size as a qcode. This theoretical maximum is up to you to decide.

Comment: First of all, I have specified many times that the string and id length are both varaible. Also, I dont not care about how much the 'maximum' string will fit in. I'm looking to _minimize_ the formula. To see how much I _can_ fit, in a QRCode. Also, 1 byte = 8 bits. In fact, most of that math is just pure wrong. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If you have relatively non-random data, a [Huffman encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding) might be a good solution.

Comment: It's worth to note that this is best fit for variable length data.

Comment: I've already theoretically Huffman encoded the strings down to the minimum 12 characters, which are each equally likely. I have maintained that each of these characters must contain the same bit-length (4-bits) to be decoded on the other side, is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

QR codes already have special encoding modes that are optimized for digits, or just alphanumeric data. It would probably be easier to take advantage of these rather than invent a scheme.

If you're going to do something custom, I think you'll find it hard to beat something like gzip compression. Just gzip the bytes, encode the bytes in byte mode, and decompress on the other end.

Comment: Actually, @Greg is right. for the tiny messages he's looking at, gzip et al have a constant overhead that bloats the message no matter what.

Comment: Yes, gzip methods are not piratical. Please also note I am also using the QR code encoding modes, but I am pre-encoding my custom string to get it to an even smaller length.

Comment: @Greg Tell us then, what is the compression method of choice for pirates? ;)

Comment: Also, whilst gzip has overhead, most of that is the headers - which zlib, the underlying compression method gzip uses, lacks. Your strings have to be very short or uncompressible for gzip to not gain you something.

Comment: I ran a little test -- for a 12-character alphabet, you'll start seeing savings at 68 bytes with GZipOutputStream. Still, I think you'll find it hard to beat QR Code's internal compression. If you restrict yourself to digits, it uses about 3.33 bits per character.

Comment: @Sean That depends on the input - what did you use? And did you try it with Zlib instead of gzip? And QR codes don't use compression per-se - they just have multiple different encoding schemes. Binary remains the most efficient for storing a sequence of integers.

Comment: Just GZipOutputStream in Java and randomly generated strings from the alphabet -- worst-case scenario. My point was to agree with you really, that it adds value even for relatively short input, in its worst form. Yes I am referring to encoding schemes -- the purpose is certainly to reduce storage, whatever you call it. I don't think the task here is to store 32-bit integers, or else none of this compression is possible indeed. What do you mean by 'binary' here? The QR code encoding for digits already uses 3.33 bits per symbol, which is just a hair above log_2(10) already.

Comment: @Sean I'm not sure if his integers are 32-bit, but they do appear to be integers. Granted, it's not much over log_2(10), but there doesn't seem much point in using it when storing the integers byte-wise is more efficient - and (hopefully) eliminates the need for delimiters.

Comment: @Sean Yes, the QR code does encode to that level, but my starting string starts at about 8 characters per ID, I can encode this down to 4 per id before I even send it to the QRCodes native algorithm. Thus, saving me log_2(10)/2 . I do think there is still one final step that could be used at the binary stage to encode 1 step further, and try for log_2(10)/3, and then on top of these three, I can also RLE the original string for additional savings, since the rest of the algorithm is bit-wise, and I've currently got 4 open operator spaces, 5 if I remove one of the delimeters (possible)

Answer (score 0):

QR codes support a binary mode, and that's going to be the most efficient way for you to store your IDs. Either:

1. Pick a length (in bytes) that is sufficient to store all your IDs, and encode the QR-code as a series of fixed-length integers. 4 bytes (32 bits) is a standard choice that ought to cover the likely range, or
2. If you want to be able to encode a wide range of IDs, but expect most of the values to be small, use a variable-length encoding scheme. One example is to use the lowest 7 bits of each byte to store the integer, and the most significant bit to indicate if there are any further bytes.

Also note that QR codes can be a lot larger than 384 characters!

Edit: From your original question, though, it looks like you're encoding more than just a series of integers - you have at least two different types of delimiters. Where can they appear and in what circumstances? The encoding format is going to depend on those parameters.

Comment: Hi Nick, The delimeters appear about as often as shown. The delimite between the ID's as an 'end of string' character, (so I'm using variable lengths). Also, are you sure about the size of QRCode? I'd question that. They can store a large series of bits, but not THAT large, especially not many ID's at 32 bits each. I'll check my sources and post a response. Also, please note that our QRCode has to be printable, and legible at 3inch's across, so our formula is about the maximum bit size QRCode we can use.

Comment: @Greg You have two different delimiters, though - why? If you only need to separate IDs, then encoding them as standard integers remains the simplest way - no need for delimiters at all. Per the Wikipedia article on QR codes, binary format ones can contain up to 2,953 bytes, but as you observe, limitations on what your camera can resolve will affect the practical limit.

Comment: I have two different delimiters because there are two seperate types of ID's and they must be grouped such that they act on eachother. 
IE: itemid|modid:modid:modid:modid|itemid:modid    etc..

Also, there is no way to distinguish just from the ID if it is a mod or an item. Also there is no set length for any given ID. I actually use two delimiters to save space this way, becuse now I can use variable length IDS.

Comment: @Greg That's kind of important information in figuring out how to encode it, no? And are the IDs actually numbers, or strings of digits? Eg, is 000123 valid and different from 123?