# Storing more info in QR Code

Tags: javascript, cordova, compression, qr-code

I am trying to develop a hybrid mobile app with QR code functionality. QR Code contains a limited number of character can be stored with it. So, I am thinking is it possible to compress the string to make it shorter so that I can store more info into the QR code?

Comment: see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5748684/encoding-strings-to-small-sizes-for-qrcode-generation

Comment: or this http://pieroxy.net/blog/pages/lz-string/index.html

Comment: @AlexNikulin Thanks you for the links. However, those compression seems to be making the string longer instead of shorter.

Comment: Look at this demo http://pieroxy.net/blog/pages/lz-string/demo.html , you can see that string will be shorter by 75% (124kb before and 30 kb after)

Comment: @AlexNikulin Before, the number of character is 62. After, the number of character is 179. So, it's longer.

Answer (score 0):

At lengths that short, most compression algorithms will actually make data longer, not shorter.  There are some algorithms which **may** work well, though… [smaz](https://github.com/antirez/smaz) comes to mind.  However, it is going to depend heavily on *what* you are trying to compress, and you haven't really provided any information about that.

Instead of thinking about compression, your best bet may be to find an encoding scheme which makes more sense for your data.  For example, if you're encoding a date and time, store it as a single number instead of text.  Think about whether you really need seconds.  If you are storing numbers, consider using variable-length quantities.  If your data is JSON, consider using protobuf instead.

If what you have really is text, it may be worth considering coming up with your own character set.  Instead of ASCII where each character 8 bits, can you limit yourself to 64 characters?  a-z, A-Z, 0-9, and two punctuation characters is only 64 possible symbols… if that is all you need, you could use a 6-bit encoding.  If the strings aren't case-sensitive you have tons of room for punctuation.

Comment: If you're only encoding uppercase text, then you could use the [alphanumeric storage mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code#Storage), which uses just 5½ bits per character.